# Как запустить программу вместе с Explorer.exe?

Tags: windows, explorer

Скажу сразу, что я делаю не какой-нибудь трой, а совсем даже наоборот =)
В общем, как можно запустить программу вместе с проводником (эксплорером) не из автозагрузки?
Просто если вместо експлорера прописать что-нибудь другое, то автозагрузка не сработает.
Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, альтернативные методы автозагрузки. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Автозагрузка бывает разная. Есть загрузка на уровне системы, когда программа запускается во время загрузки самой виндовс. Поэтому, возможно, вам подойдет что-нибудь. Вот есть программка, которая это всё видит - [AutoRuns](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/bb963902).

Как вариант: подстановка второго шелла через реестр

> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell`

Возможно, будет справедливо и в ветке `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`. Еще вариант - созать екзешник и им заменить эксплорер, и он там запускает все, что нужно, а в конце собственно запускает эксплорер. Хотя можно и в начале. Но геморроя много - нужно передать все параметры запуска;)

Comment: Вот вы пишите, что вторым способом можно перезаписать експлорер, но это не подойдет, вдруг злобный трой пропишется вместо експлорера! Не вариант. Мне надо, чтобы программа запускалась одновременно с уксплорером, не трогай его ни коим образом =) Спасибо!

Comment: у меня как-то вирус какойто сидел. в указанной ветке реестра через запятую указывался исполняемый файл=) и запускался))